# How to find out day of the week from given date in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function that accepts a string which contains a particular
>   date from the Gregorian calendar. Your function should return what day
>   of the week it was. Here are a few examples of what the input
>   string(Month Day Year) will look like. However, you should not
>   'hardcode' your program to work only for these input!

```
"June 12 2012"
"September 3 1955"
"August 4 1843"
```

> Note that each item (Month Day Year) is separated by one space. For
>   example if the input string is:

```
"May 5 1992"
```

> Then your function should return the day of the week (string) such as:

```
"Tuesday"
```

> Algorithm with sample example:

```
# Assume that input was "May 5 1992"
day (d) = 5        # It is the 5th day
month (m) = 3      # (*** Count starts at March i.e March = 1, April = 2, ... January = 11, February = 12)
century (c) = 19   # the first two characters of the century
year (y) = 92      # Year is 1992 (*** if month is January or february decrease one year)
# Formula and calculation
day of the week (w) = (d + floor(2.6m - 0.2) - 2c + y + floor(y/4) + floor(c/4)) modulo 7
after calculation we get, (w) = 2
Count for the day of the week starts at Sunday, i.e Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, ... Saturday = 6
```

> Since we got 2, May 5 1992 was a Tuesday

My first question is how do I accept `June 12 2012` as input from the user? Is there any method that allows me to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you really going to dump every homework question you get on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user_input = input('Enter the date')
```

Comment: i'll suggest you start from the docs https://docs.python.org/3/ to get yourself acquainted with python